# SQL syntax error when trying Insert from select

Tags: mysql

Try to use this query

```
  insert into `popups` (`GroupID`, `Name`,`ShortName`) VALUES
    (SELECT `GroupID`,`Name`,`ShortName` FROM `temp` WHERE `GroupID` = '1')
```

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tables `popups` and `temp` almost identical - hase same columns.

What is wrong in request?

Comment: It's either insert...values or insert...select in your case drop values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's either insert...values or insert...select in your case drop values

```
insert into `popups` (`GroupID`, `Name`,`ShortName`) 
    SELECT `GroupID`,`Name`,`ShortName` FROM `temp` WHERE `GroupID` = '1'
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html